# How to generate automatic partner deeplinks similar to website Silickdeals.net?

Tags: javascript

Trying to find the way how my website can add automatically an affiliate partner id link to the specific URL of the item.

Basically say I have partnership with Commission Junction, Linkshare and Webgains. Each provides a unique partner id for me. So say I am selling 3 specific items on my website from 3 different online stores: Newegg, BestBuy and Walmart.

I can get partnership with Newegg only via Commission Junction.
BestBuy only via Linkshare.
Walmart only via Webgains.

So I have 3 different partner ids, so how to make my website to identify the URL of the item and then place a correct affiliate partnership ID at the end of URL.